# PHP and Postgresql product

Tags: php, postgresql

Need help getting a sum for quantity and accessory_price in my current query to display in my table.

Here is my query:

```
 $query = ('SELECT accessories.accessory_name,accessory_only_solds.transaction_id,accessory_only_solds.quantity,accessory_only_solds.accessory_price,transactions.date_purchased, FROM accessory_only_solds
            left join accessories on accessory_only_solds.accessory_id = accessories.id
            left join transactions on transactions.id = accessory_only_solds.transaction_id
             ORDER BY transactions.date_purchased DESC');

 $result = pg_query($query); 
           if (!$result) { 
              echo "Problem with query " . $query . "<br/>"; 
              echo pg_last_error(); 
           exit(); 
  } 

 while($myrow = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
 printf ("<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>", htmlspecialchars($myrow['transaction_id']), htmlspecialchars($myrow['date_purchased']), htmlspecialchars($myrow['accessory_name']), htmlspecialchars($myrow['accessory_price']), htmlspecialchars($myrow['quantity']), number_format($myrow['**sumhere**'], 2));
  }
```

I tried adding this to my query but keep getting server error

```
TO_CHAR(CAST(accessory_only_solds.accessory_price AS NUMERIC)* accessory_only_solds.quantity),'999,999.99') AS atotal
```

!!!was able to solve my problem though i still need to convert the value to euro currency format.

```
 $query = ('SELECT accessories.accessory_name,accessory_only_solds.transaction_id,accessory_only_solds.quantity,accessory_only_solds.accessory_price,transactions.date_purchased,CAST(accessory_only_solds.accessory_price AS NUMERIC)*accessory_only_solds.quantity AS atotal FROM accessory_only_solds
 left join accessories on accessory_only_solds.accessory_id = accessories.id
 left join transactions on transactions.id = accessory_only_solds.transaction_id
 ORDER BY transactions.date_purchased DESC');
```

Comment: And _what_ error do you get? Or are we meant to guess that?

Comment: Sorry for not stating the value of the error. I just said server error because it is as what i saw but missed on adding the value of the error.

"Server error 500" is the error.

Was able to solve my issue though.